# Android facebook sdk how to implement new features

Tags: android, facebook

as I saw in facebook developers page they release a new sdk with some bug fixes and deprecated access_offline option. I have two applications which are using facebook login and share to facebook options and I want to implement the new fb sdk changes so my apps can work after 1st may. The problem is that I can't get how to change to the new sdk. I've changed the code,and added this

```
Facebook mFb = new Facebook("121334552177043"); 
    String access_token = settings.getString("access_token", null);
    if(access_token != null) {
        //mFb.setAccessToken(access_token);
        mFb.extendAccessTokenIfNeeded(this, null);
    }
```

to my main activity,but it's not working I guess.After I click the login with fb button in mu app it's doing nothing actually.Here is what I'm doing on button click listener :

```
mFb.authorize(MySettings.this, new String[] {"publish_stream,offline_access,email"}, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());

            String access_token = useSSLConnection.getString("access_token", mFb.getAccessToken());
            Log.i("access_token", "access_token : " + access_token);
```

and the result which I'm getting is this 'from LogCat' :

```
    03-27 15:51:57.386: I/access_token(6842): access_token : AAABuY4SL4BMBANZAOTug8ZA7ZAVR6urO8sqWX2S4SEFAZAVFzYbty4fZBZBctadMdSSIRo0Jsh0socUU0xfqeZBH4rZCeEKFPAcZD
03-27 15:51:57.446: D/RequestQueue(6842): setProxyEnabled=true
03-27 15:51:57.486: D/RequestQueue(6842): queueRequest to set proxy
03-27 15:51:57.486: D/RequestQueue(6842): setProxyConfig mProxyHost=null
03-27 15:51:57.486: D/RequestQueue(6842): queueRequest with mProxyHost=null for https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=touch&client_id=121373704577043&scope=publish_stream%2Coffline_access%2Cemail&type=user_agent&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess
03-27 15:51:57.496: D/webkit-timers(6842): [JWebCoreJavaBridge::resume] >> do resume
```

And it's not even loading the webview with login forms.
Any idea how can I solve this issue?

Comment: I just replaced the library with the latest one without any changes in code and it works fine for me.

Comment: but what did you do with sessionEvents and sessionStore files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy and paste the content of the new classes or replace them. It should work properly and don't forget to add

```
public void onResume() {    
    super.onResume();
    facebook.extendAccessTokenIfNeeded(this, null);
}
```

as Facebook suggested.

Comment: Does this approach work if the user has not got the Facebook For Android app installed?